# Triangle inequality question.

Tags: euclidean-geometry

For triangle ABC, there is a point X such that B-A-X. There is any point P on bisector of exterior angle CAX. Prove that PB+PC>AB+AC.

I have tried for many hours, but i have no idea how to solve it.
actually, i have shown PB>AB.
This is a question in 9th grade level, so please give solution by use of triangle congruency and triangle inequality.. Please don't use simillarity.

Comment: @Adriano I believe he means that the points on the line are $B, A, X$ in that order, IE that $X$ lies on the extended line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Construct point $C'$ on $BA$ extended, such that $AC= AC'$.

Prove that $AP$ is the perpendicular bisector of $CC'$. Hence $PC=PC'$.

**Hint:** Apply triangle inequality to triangle $PBC'$.

Comment: How you have got this idea?I mean it is verrrry hard for me. please tell me on what type of questions, we required constructions. THANK YOU.

Comment: @user91374 Think of how to relate the lines to each other. These kind of triangle inequality often require some reflection / rotation / translation argument. We know that we must transform $AB+AC$ into a straight line, which motivates the construction of $C'$. We then need $PC' = PC$, and so use the definition of $P$.

Comment: INTELLEGNT!!!!!